# Many to many relation can get associated object

Tags: symfony

I have a user and a school entity. This both entities have a many to many relation.

```
   class User
   {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\School")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_school",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="school_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         *      )
         */
        private $school;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->school = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    }

   class School
   {
       /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
         private $id;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

If i call the method for retriving the school id in my controller like:

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $school = $user->getSchool();
        echo $school->getId();
    }
```

I get the error message

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"
```

Can someone give me hint , what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mapping you defined, `User::$school` is a `ManyToMany`, which means the result of `getSchool` will be a `Collection` of `Schools`, not a single `School` entity.

Two scenarios:

1. A User can have multiple Schools. Then you probably should rename `$school` to `$schools` and `getSchool` to `getSchools`. And you can't call `$user->getSchools()->getId()` since `$user->getSchools()` is a `Collection` and does not have a `getId` method. Check @NoyGabay's answer for a way to access Schools ids.
2. A User can only have one School. Then you did not define your mapping correctly; you wanted a `ManyToOne` instead of `ManyToMany`. Check [Doctrine's documentation for association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional).

Comment: This is a valid answer, should be check as it.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `$user->getSchool();` is singular in method name, it returns a `PersistentCollection` - a collection of schools (since the relationship is `ManyToMany`). If you want to get a specific school's id, you would have to iterate through the schools, like so:

```
$scools = $user->getSchool()->toArray();
foreach ($scools as $scool) {
    // do something with $school
}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, should be check as it. And @sogara comments in his answer are also worth reading